# Making my own programming language

Tags: python, interpreter, language-design

This question is really to help me decide on something.  I have started development of my own *programming language* that I am calling DeliciousWaffle (or maybe samscript).

So far it looks pretty cool.  I built a compiler in Python, and associated `.dw` files with it.  These files are like `.py` or `.vbs` or `.java`.  They provide the code for the compiler to interpret. I also programmed an IDE for it using wxPython.

Here are a few examples of what it looks like:

The fully functional IDE:

[image: DWIDE]

A calculator program that I wrote in DeliciousWaffle:

[image: Calculator]

And here is the code for the compiler.  You can download this if you'd like and try out the syntax.

```
#deliciouswaffle
import sys
import linecache
varss={}
def Say(vartype,text):
    if vartype=='normal':
        print text
    if vartype=='var':
        print varss.get(str(text))
def Set(var,val):
    global varss
    varss.update({str(var):val})
def Get(var,prmpt):
    val=raw_input(prmpt)
    try:
        val=int(val)
        x=val+1
    except:
        val=str(val)
    Set(var,val)
def Loop():
    global line
    line=0
def IfStr(var1,functlines):
    global line
    var=varss.get(var1)
    try:
        x=var+1
        line+=functlines
    except TypeError:
        pass
def IfInt(var1,functlines):
    global line
    var=varss.get(var1)
    try:
        x=var+1
        pass
    except TypeError:
        line+=functlines
def Convert(var):
    val=varss.get(var)
    if type(val) == type('str'):
        val=int(val)
    if type(val) == type(1):
        val=str(val)
    varss.update({var:val})
def If(var1,compare,var2,functlines):
    global varss
    global line
    var1=varss.get(str(var1))
    var2=varss.get(str(var2))
    if compare=='equ':
        if var1==var2:
            pass
        else:
            line+=functlines
    if compare=='lss':
        if var1<var2:
            pass
        else:
            line+=functlines
    if compare=='gtr':
        if var1>var2:
            pass
        else:
            line+=functlines
def ChangeVar(var,operation,do):
    global varss
    val=varss.get(var)
    if operation=='+':
        val+=do
    if operation=='-':
        val-=do
    if operation=='/':
        val/=do
    if operation=='*':
        val*=do
    varss.update({var:val})
def CombineVars(newvar,var1,var2,operation):
    global varss
    var1=int(varss.get(var1))
    var2=int(varss.get(var2))
    if operation=='+':
        val=var1+var2
    if operation=='-':
        val=var1-var2
    if operation=='/':
        val=var1/var2
    if operation=='*':
        val=var1*var2
    varss.update({newvar:val})
def End():
   global eof
   eof=1
line=0
eof=0

try:
    program = (sys.argv[1])
except:
    program = 'main.dw'

if program == 'main.dw':
    try:
        f=open('main.dw','r')
        f.close()
    except:
        print 'No Delicious Waffle script loaded.'
        print 'Create a script called main.dw, or load one into Delicious Waffle.'
        raw_input()
        sys.exit()

while eof==0:
    try:
        line+=1
        try:
            eval(linecache.getline(program, line))
        except:
            pass
    except:
        eof=1
        f=open('tempvars.file','w')
        f.close()
        sys.exit()
```

What do you think?  Is this worth completing?  Or should I leave it be?  This question is probably inappropriate for code review, sorry.

Comment: `compiler to interpret` - Umm... compilers don't interpret stuff. Please correct such core terminology issues. [This](http://www.c4learn.com/c-programming/compiler-vs-interpreter/) should help clear it up.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I second the recommendation to invent a grammar and use a real parser.  A recursive descent parser is very easy to write, and a great place to start.  You might also have a look at a [PEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar) (Parsing Expression Grammar).  It's almost as easy to use a PEG as it is to write a recursive descent compiler, and a PEG can parse more grammars than can a recursive descent compiler.
Here are two PEGs for Python (I haven't used either of them, so can't vouch for them):

- [pyPeg](http://fdik.org/pyPEG/)
- [parsimonious](https://github.com/erikrose/parsimonious)

I don't see a good reason to get the Dragon book *yet*.  Much of what it teaches is how to *write* the LEXX/YACC type tools, along with language theory.  I think it's too deep and too low level for someone who just wants to try creating a language in order to see how it's done.  If, however, you do want to dive that deep, it is a very good book.

I would, for now, steer clear of a traditional lex/yacc setup.  That's a harder road that can wait until you've had some experience with simpler schemes.  However, if you do want to go there, [PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/) is a lex/yacc type parser for Python.

Comment: I don't mean to be a nuisance, but I am not understanding how to use the pasrsers.. would you mind explaining how I transcode that to interpret my own syntax? I read up on all the pages you've suggested.. and it isn't making sense.

Comment: @Sam, I started to, but it's too big a subject.  I think I would recommend starting with a recursive descent compiler, though.  That's the simplest thing.

Comment: @SamTubb `How to use parsers?` "The GOLD Parsing System" is a parser which doesn't have a python engine but which IMO has good documentation: [the overview](http://www.goldparser.org/about/how-it-works.htm) is that you a) define a "grammar" for your language; b) feed the grammar, plus some text (e.g. "source code" or "script") written into the language, into the parser c) the parser outputs an "abstract syntax tree" version, which is (theoretically) easier for you to process than the original script text. The [grammar](http://www.goldparser.org/grammars/index.htm) syntax is parser-specific.

Comment: I understand now! But I think I'm just going to stick to my method for now. Maybe if this ever becomes serious I'll use pyPeg, I like that one.

Answer (score 10):

It is a beginning. But currently your code is just a thin wrapper around Python function calls. And of course, there is a security problem with "eval", because someone could format your harddisk with the right line, if you execute scripts from untrusted sources.

Maybe you should invent a nice syntax for your language. An easy method to write a parser for it, would be a top-down parser (or recursive descent parser), for simple expressions as demonstrated [here](http://effbot.org/zone/simple-top-down-parsing.htm).

Later, you could even build a parser tree and convert it to assembly. The so-called ["dragon book"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principles_of_Compiler_Design) is the best reference, if you want to know more about building parsers and compilers.

Comment: I've heard people recommend "the dragon book" but didn't find it practical. Perhaps more practical if you want to write a parser is to learn to use a well-known tool like "YACC"; or I chose a less-well-known but perhaps-easier tool, the "GOLD Parsing System". They're for parsing relatively complicated programming languages, though.

Comment: I might suggest one of the Modern Compiler Design in [ML|C|Java] by A. Appel slightly more direct books and just as rewarding for most

Comment: I think I'm just going to stick to the thin wrapper for now, thank you for your help though. At least I learned something from this.